# Android WebView causes StrictMode violation

Tags: android, performance, webview, android-strictmode

I'm noticing that StrictMode is complaining quite loudly about WebView creation. Is there any way to improve the startup performance of a WebView object? I'm instantiating from XML in my onCreate() method.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(20);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

WebSettings wb = webView.getSettings();
wb.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
```

Here is the first of many StrictMode warnings:

```
D/StrictMode(22781): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=1869 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:745)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong(SQLiteStatement.java:106)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion(SQLiteDatabase.java:928)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getInstance(WebViewDatabase.java:196)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1002)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:979)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:969)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:214)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1660)
D/StrictMode(22781):    at com.myapplication.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:886)
```

Comment: Similar problem when creating a WebView in code: new WebView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());. It triggers Read/Write disk violations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to improve the startup performance of a WebView object?

Not with respect to that specific `StrictMode` complaint, since it is coming from the `WebView` constructor.

In general, there is nothing you can do about `WebView` triggering `StrictMode` -- since it is a widget, it may not be safe for you to do much with the `WebView` on a background thread, particularly once it is part of the view hierarchy.

You might scan http://b.android.com to see if there are existing bug reports about this, and if not, create a sample project that generates the message and file it along with a bug report.

Comment: The bug has been reported: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1375

Comment: @MilošČernilovský: Yes. It was reported by me.

Comment: @CommonsWare the link's dead, why did you report in the preview and not the main android repo?

Comment: @TWiStErRob: Probably because non-preview framework issues get ignored, in general. For the M Developer Preview (and perhaps L), they used a separate issue tracker. which is why that link broke. This year's N Developer Preview used labels in the main issue tracker, which will help, until such time as they discontinue that issue tracker (since it's part of the defunct Google Code service).

Answer (score 3):

A solution that worked for me (Android 5.0) was to create a dummy WebView before setting StrictMode:

```
…
new WebView(this);

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .detectAll()
        .penaltyLog()
        .build());

StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
        .detectAll()
        .penaltyLog()
        .build());
…
```

Comment: In kotlin: StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build())

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build())

Answer (score 1):

If you're bothered by the StrictMode violation or it crashes your app you can use `StrictMode.allowThreadDisk*()`:

```
ThreadPolicy realPolicy = StrictMode.allowThreadDiskReads();
try {
    web = new WebView(container.getContext());
} finally {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(realPolicy);
}
```

But, sadly allowing reads is not enough:

```
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=546 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=245 violation=1
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:732)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1755)
    at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getInstance(WebViewDatabase.java:243)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:981)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:958)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:948)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:939)
    at MyFragment.onCreateView(CategoryHelpFragment.java:41)
```

So the final workaround is:

```
ThreadPolicy realPolicy = StrictMode.allowThreadDiskWrites();
try { // in older versions of Android WebViewDatabase.getInstance creates/opens a DB and StrictMode complains
    web = new WebView(container.getContext());
} finally {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(realPolicy);
}
```

I used manual `WebView` creation, but you can just put this around `setContentView`.